# How to replace values of first n rows after filtering dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose we have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'text':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], 'values':[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

In this DataFrame, how to filter data for `values=0`, and from filtered data, we want to replace values of text column for the first n rows?

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Updated with expected output @mozway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mask and boolean indexing:

```
m = df['values'].eq(1)
df.loc[m.cumsum().le(4)&m, 'text'] += 'o'
```

Output:

```
  text  values
0   Ao       1
1    B       0
2    C       0
3    D       0
4   Eo       1
5   Fo       1
6    G       0
7   Ho       1
8    I       0
9    J       1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
*Step 1:* Filter data for the given condition and get the list of n indices for which we want to update values. In this case, let's assume we are updating values for first 4 rows after filtering data:

```
filered_index = list(df[df.values==0]['text'].index)[:4] 
filered_index
```

Output:
`[1,2,3,6]`

Step 2: In the next step, use the `filtered_index` and select the column `text` to update the values:

```
df.loc[filered_index, 'text'] = df.loc[filered_index]['text'].apply(lambda x: x+'o')
df
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope this was helpful!!